# No thumbnail shown in Laravel's File Manager

Tags: php, laravel, file-manager

Currently using Laravel version 5.7.13 with Unisharp's CKEditor & File-Manager

I successfully linked the directories to show the images that I have in the file. However, the thumbnails were not shown.

[image: The file manager with no thumbnail shown]

Is the problem lies in my directory routing (lfm.php)?

[image: My lfm.php config]

Edit 1: Just found the solution for my problem, apparently the thumbnails were "broken" due to the link provided. Then, I changed my ***filebrowserImageBrowseUrl*** in the CKEditor's script to a raw url without the 'index.php'.

Before: ../../laravel-filemanager?type=Images

After: http : //localhost/[root-directory]/public/laravel-filemanager?type=Images

In conclusion, the 'index.php' is preventing the thumbnails from showing up. 
Now it's working perfectly.